# I need to find the first maximum element in a 2D matrix using java but the code doesn't seem to work like i wanted it to. Can anyone help me?

Tags: java

1. I need the maximum elements position if there is more than one maximum element then the first one is to be printed.
2. My code prints the position of the maximum element but not the first one.
3. I don't understand why the last iteration is not working as I intend it to.

Please solve it using only Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // define lengths
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        
        // add length to matrix
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][m];
        
        // insert elements
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        // define max
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] > max) {
                    max = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            // System.out.print(i + " " + j);
        }
        // System.out.print(max + " ");
        
        // print index of highest element
        // int pos1 = 0;
        // int pos2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == max) {
                    System.out.print(i + " " + j); 
                    break;
                }
            // pos2 += 1;
            break;
            }
        // pos1 += 1;
        // break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having only a variable for the max value also have one for the index of the max value so you don't need the last loop. `int[] maxPos = new int[2];`

Comment: I tried that but it does not help.
Test input:
3 4
0 3 2 4
2 3 5 5
5 1 2 3
Correct output:
1 2

Your code output:
2 0


It should print pos (1, 2), but it prints pos (2, 0).

Comment: max should be initialize with Integer.MIN_VALUE;. Because you can have a matrix with all negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new variable to hold the position of the max value and set it in the current loop

```
int max = matrix[0][0];
int[] maxPos = new int[2];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] > max) {
            max = matrix[i][j];
            maxPos[0] = i;
            maxPos[1] = j;
        }
    }            
}
```

and then remove the rest of the code and print the result

```
System.out.printf("Max is %d and is found at [%d, %d]\n", max, maxPos[0], maxPos[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, dude this one also works. I was only stuck at the `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
But this one is a better way to solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go through the matrix twice. When you are searching for the max, store also the coordinates of the matrix where that max was found. A code example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // define lengths
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        
        // add length to matrix
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][m];
        
        // insert elements
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        // define max
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, row=0, col=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] > max) {
                    max = matrix[i][j];
                    row=i;
                    col=j;
                }
            }
            
        }
        System.out.print("max: "+max + " is at: ");
        System.out.print(col + " " + row); //indexes starting from zero   
    }
}
```

Comment: max should be initialize with Integer.MIN_VALUE;. Because you can have a matrix with all negative numbers.

Comment: @Ashu.exe welcome to stackoverflow.com! No, It doesn't. if an answer works for you don't forget to accept it. If you don't know how you can look [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: (what doesn't? OP accepted the other answer by the way)